# Show/Hide Series in Bokeh Chart Based on Widget Selection

Tags: python, bokeh

Given the following bokeh chart (this code must be run in a jupyter notebook):

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Dark2_5 as palette
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, row, column
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxButtonGroup
import itertools
import numpy as np

output_notebook()

# create a new plot (with a title) using figure
p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=400, title="My Line Plot")

start = 10.0
x = range(20)
colors = itertools.cycle(palette) 
nseries = 50

# add a line renderer
for n in range(nseries):
    y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(1,20))
    p.line(x, y, line_width=1, legend=str(n), color=next(colors))

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy="hide"

checkbox_button_group = CheckboxButtonGroup(
        labels=[str(n) for n in range(nseries)], active=[0, 1])

show(column([p, checkbox_button_group])) # show the results
```

Which produces a chart like this:

[image]

How can I connect up the checkbox buttons so that they show/hide the relevant series on the plot?

Note:
I know that I can click the legend to achieve this effect. However, I want to plot more series than the legend can show (e.g. it only shows 13 series in the screenshot). Obviously, people will only have maybe 10 series shown at any one time otherwise it becomes hard to see information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. It feels clunky though, is there a better solution? Also, how can I call my callback automatically when the plot has loaded, so that series [0,1,2,3] only are made active?

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Dark2_5 as palette
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, row, column
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxButtonGroup
import itertools
import numpy as np

output_notebook()

# create a new plot (with a title) using figure
p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=400, title="My Line Plot")

start = 10.0
x = range(20)
colors = itertools.cycle(palette) 
nseries = 50

series = []

# add a line renderer
for n in range(nseries):
    y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(1,20))
    series.append(p.line(x, y, line_width=1, legend=str(n), color=next(colors)))

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy="hide"

js = ""
for n in range(nseries):
    js_ = """
        if (checkbox.active.indexOf({n}) >-1) {{
            l{n}.visible = true
        }} else {{
            l{n}.visible = false
        }} """
    js += js_.format(n=n)

callback = CustomJS(code=js, args={})
checkbox_button_group = CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=[str(n) for n in range(nseries)], active=[0,1,2,3], callback=callback)
callback.args = dict([('l{}'.format(n), series[n]) for n in range(nseries)])
callback.args['checkbox'] = checkbox_button_group

show(column([p, checkbox_button_group])) # show the results
```

Comment: Is it important for you to run in the notebook? I could tell you for bokeh server and standalone html for doing something once the plot has loaded

Comment: No, in fact the prod app is running in flask. The notebook snippet was just to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I added a bokeh server example to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is fine.
Here is a more compact js callback that relies on the line being numbered with their "name" attribute

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Dark2_5 as palette
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, row, column
from bokeh.models import CheckboxButtonGroup, CustomJS
import itertools
import numpy as np

# create a new plot (with a title) using figure
p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=400, title="My Line Plot")

start = 10.0
x = range(20)
colors = itertools.cycle(palette) 
nseries = 50

# add a line renderer
for n in range(nseries):
    y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(1,20))
    p.line(x, y, line_width=1, legend=str(n), color=next(colors), name=str(n))

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy="hide"

checkbox_button_group = CheckboxButtonGroup(
        labels=[str(n) for n in range(nseries)], active=[])

code = """
active = cb_obj.active;
rend_list = fig.renderers;

for (rend of rend_list) {
    if (rend.name!==null) {
        rend.visible = !active.includes(Number(rend.name));
    }
}
"""

checkbox_button_group.callback = CustomJS(args={'fig':p},code=code)

show(column([p, checkbox_button_group])) # show the results
```

It's also useful if you want to hide groups of lines via keywords by having them share those in their "name" attribute

And here is how you can do it with the bokeh server:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Dark2_5 as palette
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CheckboxButtonGroup, CustomJS
import itertools
import numpy as np

# create a new plot (with a title) using figure
p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=400, title="My Line Plot")

start = 10.0
x = range(20)
colors = itertools.cycle(palette) 
nseries = 50

# add a line renderer
line_list = []
for n in range(nseries):
    y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(1,20))
    line_list += [p.line(x, y, line_width=1, legend=str(n), color=next(colors))]

p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy="hide"

checkbox_button_group = CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=[str(n) for n in range(nseries)], active=[])

def update(attr,old,new):
    for lineID,line in enumerate(line_list):
        line.visible = lineID in new

checkbox_button_group.on_change('active',update)

curdoc().add_root(column([p, checkbox_button_group]))

def init_active():
    checkbox_button_group.active = range(3)

curdoc().add_timeout_callback(init_active,1000)
```